# before_action with "or" statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have several different user types within my application. I was trying to do something like this when accessing a controller;

```
class Admins::ProgrammesController < ApplicationController
  # only allow entry if the user is one of these types.
  before_action :authenticate_admin! || :authenticate_super_admin! || :authenticate_programme_leader! || :authenticate_caseworker!

  def index
  end
```

To check the users type is allowed to access this controller.

Alas, that does not seem to be right. Rails only pays attention to the first `before_action` argument - checks if the user is admin. So my spec does not pass if user is caseworker for example.

How can I achieve this in a similar way?

**UPDATE**

As requested, more code..

This is my failing spec;

```
RSpec.describe Admins::ProgrammesController, :type => :controller do
  context 'authenticated user' do
    before :each do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create :caseworker
      sign_in @user
    end

    describe 'GET index' do
      it 'responds with a 200 OK status code' do
        get :index
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am 100% confident that the Casework type user is being created. Here is the factory;

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :caseworker, class: 'Users::Caseworker' do
    email { "me@example.com" }
    password { "password" }
  end
end
```

Here is the relevant lines from the routes file;

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: 'users/sessions'}, skip: :registrations
  devise_for :admins, class_name: 'Users::Admin'
  devise_for :caseworker, class_name: 'Users::Caseworker'
  devise_for :cardholder, class_name: 'Users::Cardholder'
  devise_for :programme_leader, class_name: 'Users::ProgrammeLeader'
  devise_for :super_admin, class_name: 'Users::SuperAdmin'

  scope module: 'admins' do
    # this is the route in question...
    resources :programmes, only: [:index, :show, :new]
```

Comment: Are admin, super_admin etc. separate devise scopes (i.e. is :authenticate_admin! the method devise gives you for free or is it something you've written yourself? If the latter, what does it do?)

Comment: it's something I've written myself. It's STI basically. There are a few different types of Users that can be created. User is the parent class of each. They don't do anything special right now, they are just different types of user.

Comment: Can you show the authentication methods?

Comment: @SinanGuclu authentication methods??! I haven't constructed those myself. I am just using Devise.

Answer (score 0):

define a custom method in

```
## application_controller.rb

def authenticate!
  if [ current_admin, current_super_admin, current_programme_leader,current_caseworker ].all? {|e| e.nil?}
    :authenticate_admin! ### We can only redirect to one sign in page if there is no user logged in
  end
end
```

and use this method in your controller

```
before_action :authenticate!
```

Comment: So what happens in my next controller when only `super_admin` and `admin` are allowed access? - I won't be able to use this

Comment: `defined? current_admin` will always be true, because there is a method of that name (even if that method returns nil)

Comment: Tweak it. You can pass user models allowed as arguments to the authenticate method .

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
authenticate_admin! || authenticate_super_admin! || ...
```

Doesn't work because if (for example) an admin is not signed in `authenticate_admin!` will trigger the redirect. It doesn't matter what happens next, the redirect still happens.

You can write a filter easily enough, for example

```
def check_authenticated?
  if current_admin || current_super_admin ...
    #let them in
  else
    #redirect them
  end
end
```

But there is also the concept of [devise groups](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers/ClassMethods:devise_group) which allows you to do something like

```
class Admins::ProgrammesController < ApplicationController
  devise_group :programme_editor, contains: %i(admin super_admin case_worker)
  before_action :authenticate_programme_editor!
end
```

Within this controller you'll get the usual helpers: `current_programme_editor`, `programme_editor_signed_in?` which find / check the existence of any of the named things, in the order specified.

You also get `current_programme_editors` which is all of the users etc. rather than just the first one.

Comment: Can you provide more code please? You are dealing with a Rails beginner. I don't follow the syntax well

Comment: What don't you understand, other than me forgetting the before_action in he second case

Comment: well adding the `before_action` helped :)

Comment: I'll have to do more tests but this current one seems to work with this solution..